# After Migrating from spring boot 2.6.2 to 2.6.6 , getting org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

**Error logs:**

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_202]  at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
> [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
> [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
> [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
> [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
> [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]     at
> com.walmart.ebs.people.system.payroll.data.sync.SpringBootApplicationStarter.main(SpringBootApplicationStarter.java:19)
> [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
> at
> org.springframework.integration.support.json.JacksonJsonUtils.(JacksonJsonUtils.java:58)
> ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]  at
> org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:139)
> ~[spring-integration-kafka-5.5.10.jar:5.5.10]     at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:735)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]   at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:163)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]   at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:426)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:92)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindConsumer(BindingService.java:184)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:137)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:118)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
> ~[na:1.8.0_202]   at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
> ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]   ... 14 common frames omitted
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Why just don't migrate to the latest version of Spring Boot: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this version of spring boot have spring-integration-core  version 5.5.10 which has a bug which was causing the issue, so i had to manually define the version of spring integration core in pom file. 5.5.11 should  fix this isssue

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

upgrade to later java version might help. Your issue could be you are still using java version < 9. I suggest upgrading to 11 or 17 and trying again to see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The newer Spring Boot version upgraded Spring Integration to version 5.5.10 which [introduced a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3761#issuecomment-1079909663) that accidentally added a dependency on Java 9. The Spring Integration documentation says [Java 8 should be supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.5.10/reference/html/preface.html#supported-java-versions). If you upgrade to Spring Boot 2.6.7, then you will get the Spring Integration version containing the bug fix.

Comment: ... or just used newer Java! I'm surprised how many people still use Java 8... I know that was my bad to cherry-pick commit without double check. Now we have a `options.release = 8` in Gradle to avoid this type of errors.